# Angular ngrx store not getting latest value

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am passing a parameter to an "Account Detail" page, that calls a Web Api to get the account details.

The first time i load the "Account Detail" page nothing is shown, if i go into another account, the details for the previous account are shown (this continues on, i.e. the next account will show the previous one).

I've tried changing the order of the dispatch and select, also tried moving the dispatch to the constructor but i'm still getting the same behaviour.

This is what i am currently doing....

Account Details - (CustomerAccountDetailed contains the values)

```
actionsSubscription: Subscription;
customerAccount$: Observable<CustomerAccountDetailed>;

constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>,
    private actions: SalesLedgerActions,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actionsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.store.dispatch(this.actions.fetchSingleCustomerAccount(params.id));
        this.customerAccount$ = this.store.select(getCustomerAccount);
    });
  }

public ngOnDestroy(): void  {
    this.actionsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

SalesLedgerEffects

```
@Effect()
FetchSingleAccount$ = this.actions$
   .ofType(SalesLedgerActions.FETCH_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT)
   .switchMap((action: Action) => {
      return this.customerApiService.getCustomerDetail(action.payload);
})
   .map((customerAccount: ItemDto<CustomerAccountDetailed>) => this.actions.fetchSingleCustomerAccountSuccess(customerAccount));
```

salesLedgerReducer

```
case SalesLedgerActions.FETCH_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
    const customerAccount: ItemDto<CustomerAccountDetailed> = payload as ItemDto<CustomerAccountDetailed>;
    return Object.assign({}, state, { selectedAccount: customerAccount.result as CustomerAccountDetailed }) as ISaleLedgerState;
```

selectors

```
export function fetchCustomerRecord(state: ISaleLedgerState): any {
return state.selectedAccount;
}

// *************************** PUBLIC API's ****************************
export const getCustomerAccount: any = createSelector(getSalesLedgerState, fetchCustomerRecord);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move this out of your `subscription` and put it into your constructor:

```
this.customerAccount$ = this.store.select(getCustomerAccount);
      });
```